# Why is my child not returning

Tags: python, pexpect

When I run this script on both ASAOS and IOS devices it find that they are different in the enable_mode function, and issues  'terminal pager 0' for ASAOS, and 'terminal length 0' for IOS.

Then in the main function I have a 'show run' command issued. This command is issued on the IOS device, but it seems to stop right after the 'terminal pager 0' command is issued on the ASA.

Is it safe to assume that the only output to the console (other then 'print') is the last successful string?

Here is what I get when I run the script

terminal pager 0

home-as <= name of the ASA minus the last letter for some reason

show run <= show run command issued on the IOS switch

Building configuration...

[EXTRACTED]

```
def enable_mode(user, host, passwd, en_passwd):
    ssh_newkey = 'Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?'
    constr = 'ssh ' + user + '@' + host
    child = pexpect.spawn(constr)
    ret = child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, ssh_newkey, '[P|p]assword:'])

    if ret == 0:
        print '[-] Error Connecting to ' + host
        return
    if ret == 1:
        child.sendline('yes')
        ret = child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT])
        if ret == 0:
            print '[-] Could not accept new key from ' + host
            return
    child.sendline(passwd)
    auth = child.expect(['[P|p]assword:', '.>', '.#'])
    if auth == 0:
        print 'User password is incorrect'
        return
    if auth == 1:
        child.sendline('enable')
        child.sendline(en_passwd)
        enable = child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, '.#'])
        if enable == 0:
            print 'enable password for ' + host + ' is incorrect'
            return
        if enable == 1:
            child.sendline(SHOWVER)
            what_os = child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, '.IOS.', '.Adaptive.'])
            if what_os == 0:
                print 'show ver' + ' time out' + 'for ' + host
                return
            if what_os == 1:  # IOS
                child.sendcontrol('c')
                child.expect(PRIV_EXEC_MODE)
                child.sendline(IOSTERMLEN0)
                child.expect(PRIV_EXEC_MODE)
                return child
            if what_os == 2:  # ASAOS
                child.sendline(QOUTMORE)
                child.expect(PRIV_EXEC_MODE)
                child.sendline(ASATERMPAGER0)
                child.expect(PRIV_EXEC_MODE)
                return child

def main():
    conf_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__, formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
                                          add_help=False)
    conf_parser.add_argument('--conf_file', help='Specify a conf file', metavar='FILE')
    conf_parser.add_argument('--host_file', dest='hosts', type=file, help='specify a target host file')
    args, remanaing_argv = conf_parser.parse_known_args()

    if args.conf_file:
        conf = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
        conf.read([args.conf_file])
        defaults = dict(conf.items('Defaults'))
    else:
        defaults = {'option': 'default'}
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[conf_parser])
    parser.set_defaults(**defaults)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    hosts = args.hosts
    user = args.user
    passwd = args.passwd
    en_passwd = args.en_passwd

    if hosts:
        for line in hosts:
            host = line.rstrip()
            child = enable_mode(user, host, passwd, en_passwd)
            if child:
                current_time = time.strftime('%m.%d.%y.%M.%S', time.localtime())
                output_name = "cisco_configs/{0}_{1}.txt".format(host, current_time)
                sys.stdout = open(output_name, 'w')
                send_command(child, SHOWRUN)
    else:
        print('I need hosts!!')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you narrow down your problem some more? I know about pexpect, but I don't know about the details of your systems, and it's hard to understand what's actually going wrong.

Comment: Under "if what_os == 2:  # ASAOS" it spits out the "ASATERMPAGER0" command, that's where I see my first output from the script "terminal pager 0". Then after that it goes right to the IOS device and does the full show run. If I move the last "child.expect(PRIV_EXEC_MODE)" off my config_mode function to the main function right before "send_command(child, SHOWRUN)" the ASA does the show run but the IOS device will not. Something to do with the expect maybe?

Comment: I can't see how moving the expect call would make a difference. How are you seeing what the script is sending?

Comment: I'm not really "seeing" anything but the output of the script. When the output is "terminal pager 0" I know thats the call from "child.sendline(ASATERMPAGER0)", and the next thing should be the output of "show run" on the ASA but it just moves on to the IOS switch. I'm calling a host list and the ASA is fist on the list, then the switch. I added a print "done" at the end of main and the order of events where "terminal pager 0", home-as, "done", "show run from IOS switch", "done". terminal pager 0 seems to be the last thing the ASA child has before losing it.

Comment: But the script you've shown never outputs that - there's no print, no writes to sys.stdout or anything. Is there something separate on the 'ASA' and 'IOS' devices that reports what commands are sent to them?

Comment: I've updated the code with a sys.stdout to a file. For The IOS device I get a full show run like expected. For the ASA I only get    terminal pager 0
home-as                                                                          The terminal pager 0 is called at if what_os == 2, then child.sendline(ASATERMPAGER0). Thanks for your help. If it helps, you can look at the full code @ https://github.com/Secure-Consulting/Cisco_Config_Mgr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. I was using a variable "QOUTMORE" under "enable_mode" and "if what_os == 2". This variable was set to 'q' in another module called with "from modules.cmds import *", but instead I used a 'q' and not the variable in my "enable_mode" function. Not sure why its working but it is.

Comment: Possibly more important: you've changed one call from `sendline` to `send`. `sendline` adds a newline after the characters you send, whereas `send` doesn't.

Comment: Good call, that extra line must have been quiting out of the ASA before it was able to send show run. Because 'q' alone without the new line will quit the "more" like status when doing a show command. So I probaly could leave the variable but stick with send vs sendline. I'm going to give it a shot. Thanks for your help!